# AWS S3 PNG image not working with FPDF

Tags: php, amazon-s3, fpdf

On my PHP FPDF script

```
<?php
...
$mypdf->Image("http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/path/to/the/image/file.png", null, null, 150, 150);
...
?>
```

and it causes errors. However when I try to do the same thing but with a different image not hosted on S3, it works.

How is this possible that S3 does not work with FPDF?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and I after some digging in the fpdf source figured out the issue was with [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).  In order to use this method with an S3 image you need to use an [S3 Stream Wrapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html).  This requires the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/index.html) or you could also roll your own if really wanted to.

My code looks like this

```
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('KEY','SECRET');
$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version'=>'latest',
    'region'      => 'REGION',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);
$client->registerStreamWrapper();

// Link to file
$url = 's3://bucket/key';

// add background image
$fpdf->Image($url, 0, 0, $fpdf->GetPageWidth(), $fpdf->GetPageHeight());
```